# how to get numpy where for 1st True Only

Tags: python, numpy

i have array of data as given below.

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

i want to get conditional formatting like `a>5`

i can get it with `np.where`.  But np.where is continuous checking for next true

```
np.where(a>5,'T','F')
> array(['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T'], dtype='<U1')
```

i want to skip the consecutive True Value like when `a>5` comes to 6 its `True` but for 7 also it is `True` which i dont want. I want only 1st one.

But also if value drops from  7 to 4 and again rise to 6 then that 6 should be `True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.roll` to shift the values and then check if original element is True and shifted element is False

```
a_bool = a > 5
a_shifted_bool = np.roll(a_bool, 1)
a_shifted_bool[0] = False # first element is last element of a_bool, which we need to ignore

np.where(a_bool & ~a_shifted_bool, 'T', 'F')
array(['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F',
       'T'], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Neat idea ! To make it closer to OP's requirement, instead of `np.where()`, your last statement could be `np.nonzero(a_bool & ~a_shifted_bool)[0]`

Comment: is `np.roll`  vs  `df.shift(1)` are same

Comment: There is just one difference. In `np.roll`, the last element of the array becomes the first element, but with `df.shift(1)`, the first element becomes `np.nan`. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html - Elements that roll beyond the last position are re-introduced at the first.

Answer (score 0):

I guess @Suraj S analyze stock with Best Times of the value to Buy and Sell Stocks.

I try other example, and I think @ggaurav answer is a good way, I learn more in your answer.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7,8,4,2,3,6,4,7,9,4,1,2,3,2,5])

a_bool = a > 5
a_shifted_bool = np.roll(a_bool, 1)
a_shifted_bool[0] = False # first element is last element of a_bool, which we need to ignore

np.where(a_bool & ~a_shifted_bool, 'T', 'F')
```

`array(['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], dtype='<U1')`

Comment: ohh yes i try it for stocks :)